# WPF Binding Fundamentals

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to `WPF` and the binding. I see the following through the application and I was wondering what the difference is.

```
{Binding aField}
{Binding Path=aField}
```

When should I use one over the other?

Comment: No difference between the two. Once just explicitly states that its a path. I would highly suggest the Pluralsight courses on WPF

Comment: and btw bad naming because you can just bind to a property and not a field ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference; In the first example you are creating the binding using the constructor [`Binding(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in the second one you are assigning a property using the initializer, calling the [`Binding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597577%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. `Path` is a default property and does not need to be specified in binding markup extension [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Binding markup extension uses Binding.Path as a conceptual "default property", where Path= does not need to appear in the expression. If you specify a Binding expression with an implicit path, the implicit path must appear first in the expression, prior to any other bindProp=value pairs where the Binding property is specified by name. For example: {Binding PathString}, where PathString is a string that is evaluated to be the value of Binding.Path in the Binding created by the markup extension usage. You can append an implicit path with other named properties after the comma separator, for example, {Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}.